# How to pass custom parameters to a ViewModel using Factory?

Tags: java, android, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

I am aware in order to pass custom parameters to **ViewModel**, we can use **ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory**, Like this:

```
// Factory Class    
class MyFactory extends ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory {

        private final String mId;
        public MyFactory(String id) {
            mId = id;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public <T extends ViewModel> T create(@NonNull Class<T> modelClass) {
            return (T) new MyViewModel(mId);
        }
    }


// MyViewModel class
class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {

  public MyViewModel(String id) {
     ...
  }
}

// Activity I can Initialise as: 
MyFactory modelFactory = new MyFactory(id);
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, modelFactory).get(MyViewModel.class);
```

How can I achieve the same with custom parameters in the **AndroidViewModel** subclass along with the Application context. Like

```
// MyAndroidViewModel class
    class MyAndroidViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

      public MyViewModel(Application context, String id) {
         super(context);
         ...
      }
    }
```

How to initialise **MyAndroidViewModel** and how **ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory** comes into play here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this problem previously and I managed it by doing this. In your activity create your `ViewModel` factory as below :

```
//Inside MyActivity
ViewModelProvider.Factory factory = new ViewModelProvider.Factory() {
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public <T extends ViewModel> T create(@NonNull Class<T> modelClass) {
                return (T) new MyAndroidViewModel(getApplication(),
                        "My string!");
            }
        };
```

And then use it to create your `ViewModel` :

```
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory).get(MyAndroidViewModel.class);
```

**UPDATE:**

As the `ViewModelProviders` class has been deprecated, the updated answer would be as below. The factory is the same as before, it has just changed to Kotlin.

```
var factory = object : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
        override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
            return  SimpleAndroidViewModel(activity!!.application,
                "My string!") as T
        }
    }
```

However, the line where we were creating the ViewModel instance has changed and now we are using the `ViewModelProvider` class.

```
private val viewModel: SimpleAndroidViewModel by lazy {
        ViewModelProvider(this, factory).get(SimpleAndroidViewModel::class.java)
    }
```

Comment: in the factory, I am myself passing the **context  (Activity context here == MemoryLeak)**, what is the use of extending `AndroidViewModel` if I still pass the context argument myself?

Comment: @AadilMehraj We are passing the application context to the `viewmodel`, as application context is tied to application lifecycle (whereas activity context is tied to activity lifecycle) it is fine to have it in `viewmodel` and it won't cause a memory leak (because it has no relation to our activity nor our view).
I've updated my code snippet in my answer.

Comment: What difference does it make to use **AndroidViewModel** instead of **ViewModel**, we are still passing context ourself, and not using the AndroidViewModel's context?

Comment: @AadilMehraj The only thing that **AndroidViewModel** does is to keep an instance of the application context, and this instance is passed by us to the viewModel. you can simply extend **ViewModel** (instead of **AndroidViewModel**) and add `private Application mApplication;` to your own viewmodel class to keep application context.

Comment: but, isnt thah 'ViewModelProviders.of' method deprecated ??

Comment: @MarlonLópez Thanks for noticing that, I've just updated the answer.