# How to implement the ViewModel to save the state

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-viewmodel, android-savedstate

So I have tried to implement a viewModel on my app, but it still operates the same way.
I want to save the current view of my game, but since the part that should be saved is inside a function that holds views, I couldn't move it.

Here's some of the code.

The Fragment

```
class GamePlay1Fragment : Fragment() {

//    lateinit var front_anim: AnimatorSet
//    lateinit var back_anim: AnimatorSet

    private lateinit var viewModel: GP1ViewModel
    private lateinit var pieces: List<ImageView>



    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val binding: Gameplay1FragmentBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater,
            R.layout.gameplay1_fragment,
            container, false)



        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(GP1ViewModel::class.java)


        binding.backButtonView.setOnClickListener { v: View ->
            v.findNavController().navigate(GamePlay1FragmentDirections.actionGamePlay1FragmentToLobbyFragment())
        }


        pieces = listOf(binding.card1back, binding.card2back, binding.card3back, binding.card4back,
            binding.card5back,binding.card6back, binding.card7back,
            binding.card8back, binding.card9back, binding.card10back, binding.card11back,
            binding.card12back)

        viewModel.gameCards = pieces.indices.map { index ->
            GameCard(viewModel.images[index])
        }


            pieces.forEachIndexed { index, piece ->
                piece.setOnClickListener {

                    viewModel.updatingModels(index)

                    updatingViews()
                }
            }



        return binding.root
    }

    private fun updatingViews() {
        viewModel.gameCards.forEachIndexed { index, gameCard ->
            val piece = pieces[index]
            piece.setImageResource(if (gameCard.isFacedUp) gameCard.id else allcardbacks)
        }
    }


}
```

The View-Model

```
class GP1ViewModel() : ViewModel() {

        lateinit var gameCards: List<GameCard>
        private var indexOfSelectedPiece: Int? = null



    val images = mutableListOf(
        R.drawable.memorybatcardfront,
        R.drawable.memorycatcardfront,
        R.drawable.memorycowcardfront,
        R.drawable.memorydragonfront,
        R.drawable.memorygarbagemancardfront,
        R.drawable.memoryghostdogcardfront
    )

    init {
        images.addAll(images)
        images.shuffle()
        Log.e(TAG, "ViewModel Created:")
    }






     fun updatingModels(position: Int) {
        val gameCard = gameCards[position]

        if (gameCard.isFacedUp) return


        if (indexOfSelectedPiece == null) {
            restoreGameCards()
            indexOfSelectedPiece = position

        }
        else {
            checkingForMatch(indexOfSelectedPiece!!, position)
            indexOfSelectedPiece = null
        }
        gameCard.isFacedUp = !gameCard.isFacedUp
    }

    private fun restoreGameCards() {
        val handler = Handler()
        for (gameCard in gameCards) {
            if (!gameCard.isMatched) {
                handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000)
                gameCard.isFacedUp = false

            }

        }
    }

    private fun checkingForMatch(position1: Int, position2: Int) {
        if (gameCards[position1].id == gameCards[position2].id) {
            gameCards[position1].isMatched = true
            gameCards[position2].isMatched = true
        }
    }

    private val runnable = Runnable(){
        kotlin.run {
        }
    }


}
```

The part I am assuming is that needs to be saved is the updatingView() in the fragment but I can't move it since it also dealing with an array of imageViews (S.O.C). Any ideas are welcomed, thanks.

Comment: Please take a look at [How to pass custom parameters to a ViewModel using Factory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53184891/7948109), you can also do this in fragments

Answer (score 0):

Your viewModel is using the fragment reference. Instead it should use the activity reference.

```
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(GP1ViewModel::class.java)
```

Since you are using fragment reference, it will be destroyed once the fragment is destroyed so data won't be persisted.

Another point to note is if you want you can use a SharedViewModel approach for sharing data across multiple fragment instances.

Comment: So I should call the viewModel class on the activity instead?

Comment: Not necessarily. You always have activity context in the fragment. You can use that. For example, getActivity() call inside a fragment will give you the activity. The activity is a context (since Activity extends Context).